# How to input a page of data from a pdf file?

Tags: sas

I am a beginning learner on SAS. I am wondering if you could tell me how to input this diagram into SAS. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S15Ac.jpg)

Comment: SAS can't read directly from PDF's. I'm not aware of any application that can directly. Copy and paste it into SAS and read as text.

Comment: Ok thank you for the reminding.